# Using Google Sheets to dynamically add entries to column based on logic?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I have a list of people that I have a drop down for if they are attending or not to an event.

If "Yes" I want them to be added to another column on sheet 2. Except I don't know how to add them dynamically. So if I have 50 people and only 10 say yes, how do I have the first 10 rows populate with the people?

I think excel has a table/object ability but I don't see this in excel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A:A, B:B="yes")
```

[image: 0]

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select A where B='yes'")
```

[image: 0]